# Can you use the angel token in conjunction with the rabbits foot

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

If I have both the angel feather and the rabbits foot in my hand can I make a roll, and then if I fail that roll use the rabbits foot to re-roll on die and use the angel feather to call an 8 on the re-roll?

I don't think you can but my friends say yes you can and I can't find any rule that states you can or can't either way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't expect the rules to say anything about this; the card text is intended to be the rules. There's also nothing in the [FAQ](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=ah/faqs/hoth) about it.

Angel Feather reads:

> When you attempt a roll of any kind, you can call out a number from 0 to 8. Use that number instead of rolling the dice.

To me, that fairly clearly implies that you choose the number *before* you roll - you use the number *instead* of rolling. If you could use it after you roll, I'd expect it to say something more like "After you attempt a roll of any kind, you may choose a number from 0 to 8, and use that number instead of the number you rolled."

Rabbit's Foot says:

> Once during your turn, you may reroll one die. You must keep the second roll.

Once you've rolled, it's too late to use a number instead of the roll. Once you've gone pat that and rerolled a die, you're even more clearly past that point. It sounds like you're right - you can't use these things together.

Comment: +1, You might want to indicate that the [official FAQ](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=ah/faqs/hoth) doesn't disagree with your answer [no mention of timing usage of Angel Feather], just in case someone is looking for the FAQ. What is the past tense of roll, "roll" or "rolled"? , *I'd expect it to say something more like "use that number instead of the number you roll**ed***."

Comment: @user1873 Both past and present fit there - I had present, as in "instead of the number you (are about to) roll". But I guess the more likely formulation is past.

Comment: Sounds like you answered the wrong question? He's not talking about using the feather after the second role, but rather using it after be first, instead of the second. And I'm pretty sure you can do that. Feather says before a role of "any kind." The extra role for rabbit's foot is a role of any kind."

Comment: @GendoIkari No, I think I answered the right question. The confusing thing here is that Angel Feather talking about "a roll" means "a roll of many dice" - before you roll all the dice, you pick a number. Rabbit's Foot, on the other hand, is talking about a single die (a 0, 1, or 2). The reroll that Rabbit's Foot allows (one die) is not the same thing as the roll that Angel Feather replaces (many dice).

Comment: Sorry, missed that rabbits foot is single die only. But your answer does say "once you've rolled, then rerolled, it's too late..." which sounds like you are talking about how you can't use angel feather after both rolls, rather than before the second role.

Comment: @GendoIkari Okay, revised to make that clause that even more obvious.

Answer (score -2):

Though the rules and the FAQ don't directly address this, I'm pretty sure it is allowed based on a literal reading of the cards. Angel Feather says to use it when making a roll of any kind, and re-rolling due to Rabbit's Foot's ability seems like a clear example of a roll of any kind. Angel Feather doesn't say only when making the first roll of an attempt, it just says a roll of any kind.

Comment: No, Angel Feather replaces a **roll** - the action where you roll some number of dice and add them up. Rabbit's Foot rerolls *a single die*, just a part of a **roll**. At that point, the other dice are all fixed. Angel Feather wants to replace the **roll**, all the dice, before you roll them, and by the time you're using Rabbit's Foot, it's too late to do that.

Comment: If your argument were valid, this would let you roll five dice, get 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, use the Rabbit's Foot to reroll the 0, then say "aha, I'll use the Angel Feather to replace that roll with an 8, and get a total of 15".

Comment: By the way, the reason it says "roll of any kind" is that there are a lot of different skill checks and such - roll your speed, roll your strength, make an omen roll, take two dice of damage, roll four dice, and so on. It's clarifying that it works on anything in the game that causes you to roll a set of dice, not just skill checks. It's not trying to say that it can replace the roll of a single die with a number - it works on the roll as a whole, not a single die (which is just a 0, 1, or 2).

Comment: @jefromi, Agreed. I was thinking incorrectly that Rabbit's Foot let you re-roll the entire roll. In which case I think my conclusion would be correct. But as it only lets you re-roll 1 die, I was mistaken.

Comment: @Jefromi A reroll is, by definition, another roll. Saying that the second roll, of one die, can be angelfeather'd, does not extend to allowing one die from a larger roll to be angelfeather'd.